# Heroku pg:push Can't get Database URL working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to use heroku pg:push to send the data from my local machine to my production instance on heroku.

I've looked at several posts and this is what I've tried:

On [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) I've tried:

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app [app name]
```

But my DB URL isn't aliased to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA. I've tried putting in the full database URL I see when I run

```
heroku config --app [app name]
```

But, I get an error that it needs the URL.

So I did more digging on [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

I tried running

```
heroku pg:wait
```

and

```
heroku config -s | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
```

In an attempt to get my "Color URL" but nothing gets returned when I run the command.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you run `heroku config` you get an error that it needs a URL? Can you add the error output to your question? Its not clear what exactly are the errors you're getting...

Comment: Are you running the first 2 heroku commands verbatim, or are you substituting the variables (mylocaldb, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA, [app name]) for those specific to your app?

Comment: It's also possible that if your app has never had multiple databases attached to it, the current DB hasn't been given a color alias, and is aliased as just DATABASE_URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I was substituting the actual variables for my local database and app name.

Using DATABASE_URL as the database URL worked. Thanks!